# Use javascript to input data from a website

Tags: javascript

Ive been trying to find a way to input data from a website coded in HTML with a single javascript output on it.  Is there anyway to incorperate whatever text is on the page (blank page with one line string) into a string on a javascript program I write? I have been searching for quite a while and I'm very sorry if this is a repeat question.  Thanks for all you help!

Comment: You need to provide more details . Is there a separate HTML page where the content is from where your javascript code is going to be ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry it is a separate HTML page. Is there a way to view the source code and use a value in the first page inside my HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

Say what? I'm thinking you want this, but really I'm not sure what you want.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var myJavaScriptString = document.body.innerHTML;

      /*  Do cool things with your one line string  */
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    one line string
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 seperate html pages you can use ajax and get data from 1st html page .

Are you using jquery library ? That might make this a lot cleaner and easier . Check this sample . http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/